# How to configure Spring mvc for static html files?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a spring MVC application with JSP pages. I understand that JSPs are outdated technology and want to change them to HTML files. But all the guides and stacktrace questions I'm seeing are from 4 to 8+ years ago. 
Here is my config:

```
public class InitWebApp extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {ConfigWeb.class ,DataConfig.class, ConfigSecurity.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"Controller","Config","Services"})
public class ConfigWeb implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("view/LoginPage");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/curator").setViewName("view/Curator/curatorHome");
        registry.addViewController("/student").setViewName("view/Student/studentHome");
        registry.addViewController("/change").setViewName("view/ProfileChange");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/profilePictures/**").addResourceLocations("file:///${fullPath}/resources/profilePictures/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/profilePictures/**").addResourceLocations("file:///${fullPath}/web-resources/profilePictures/");

    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

I've tried to experiment with changing view resolvers and resourceHandlers. As soon as I managed to make my Tomcat server find my index.html and open it on the start, my controllers stopped working.

Could you please help me with the direction in which I should move on?